# Combining two single sim phones (backup) into one dual sim phone

Tags: dual-sim, google-backup

Is there any method of combining the Android backups from two mobile phones when I move from two single sim phones to a dual sim phone?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 running my UK contract SIM, and a ZTE running my PAYG German sim.

I have just purchased a S9+ and I want to use both sims in the one phone. This is not an issue for me.

I have some data stored on the S4 which I do not wish to lose, and some data stored on the ZTE which I also do not wish to lose.

The Android backup show for both phones by name, but I can only use one to migrate my data.

How do I combine the data on two different phones, into a single backup that can be used on my S9.

Comment: Backups of what ? Contacts? Photos? Apps? Are both those earlier devices rooted? What Android versions are they running?  Do you plan to root the new device? Please [edit] to add these and more information that would help folks answer